# Using Multiprocessing Pool from an Interactively loaded module

Tags: python, multiprocessing, ipython, python-interactive

I have a Python module `mymodule'

```
# mymodule.py
import multiprocessing as mp

def do_work(x):
  # do some stuff
  return 42+x

def work():
  pool = mp.Pool()
  work_list= [1,2,3,4,5]
  returned_values = pool.map(do_work, work_list)
  pool.close()

#end mymodule
```

I want to import this interactively in a Python shell and invoke `work()` like this

```
 In [1]: import mymodule as mm
 In [2]: mm.work()
```

If I do this the `do_work` does not seem to be doing anything. How can I make this work in an interactive shell. If I turn the above into a non-interactive script I face no problems. I am on Windows.

Comment: You'll need to provide a [mcve], because this code doesn't work (`do_work` needs to accept an argument) and it also doesn't do anything (e.g. print any output) and if I fix those problems then it works fine in a console.

Comment: @AlexHall Changed the code to make do_work to do something minimal. It doesn't work on Ipython QtConsole. Are you on Windows too ?

Comment: The main issue is that the multiprocessing module can't find your function, look at the linked question for more info